# Regex for url rewrite with if then else

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

Given these urls:

```
1: http://site/page-name-one-123/
2: http://site/page-name-set2/
3: http://site/set20
```

I wrote this expression **that will be applied to last url segment**:

```
(?(?<=set[\d])([\d]+)|([^/]+))
```

What I'd want to do is to catch every digits followed by 'set' only if the url segment starts with 'set' and a digit immediately after; otherwise i want to use the whole segment (excluding slashes).

As I wrote this regex, it matches any character that is not a '/'. I think I'm doing something wrong in test statement.
Could anyone point me right?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
Thanks to [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/733347/josh-davenport) input I played around for a bit and found that this one fits better my needs:

```
set-(?P<number>[0-9]+)|(?P<segment>[^/]+)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this pattern can help you out, I put it together based on your requirements. You may want to play around with setting some of the groups to not capture so that you only get the segments that you need. However, it does seperate capture your *set* URL's without *set* at the start.

```
((?<=/{1})(((?<!set)[\w|-]*?)(\d+(?=/?))|((?:set)\d+)))
```

I suggest using [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to pick it apart if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`((?<=/)set\d+|(?<=/)[^/]+?set\d+)`

**Explanation**

```
<!--
Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «((?<=/)set\d+|(?<=/)[^/]+?set\d+)»
   Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «(?<=/)set\d+»
      Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=/)»
         Match the character “/” literally «/»
      Match the characters “set” literally «set»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
   Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match) «(?<=/)[^/]+?set\d+»
      Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind) «(?<=/)»
         Match the character “/” literally «/»
      Match any character that is NOT a “/” «[^/]+?»
         Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «+?»
      Match the characters “set” literally «set»
      Match a single digit 0..9 «\d+»
         Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
-->
```